# Code Repository - What exactly is CTX in pyspark for a code repo?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have seen the use of ctx in a code repo, what exactly is this? Is it a built in library? When would I use it?

I've seen it in examples such as the following:

```
df = ctx.spark.createdataframe(...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Code Repositories transformations, you can optionally include a parameter `ctx` which gives you more access to the underlying infrastructure running your job.  Typically, you'll access the `ctx.spark_session` attribute for making your own `pyspark.sql.Dataframe` objects from Python objects, like:

```py
from transforms.api import transform_df, Output
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@transform_df(
  Output=("/my/output")
)
def my_compute_function(ctx):

   schema = T.StructType(
     [
       T.StructField("name", T.StringType(), True)
     ]
   )
   return ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([["Alex"]], schema=schema)
```

You'll find a full API description in documentation on the `transforms.api.TransformContext` class, where attributes such as the `spark_session` and `parameters` are available for you to read.

Note: the `spark_session` attribute has type [pyspark.sql.SparkSession](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sparksession#pyspark.sql.SparkSession)